# Restart pod without losing changes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging

I have 2 pods that are meant to send logs to Elastic search. Logs in /var/log/messages get sent but some reason service_name.log doesn't get sent - I think it is due to the configuration for Elastic search. There is a .conf file in these 2 pods that handle the connection to Elastic Search.

I want to make changes to test if this is indeed the issue. I am not sure if the changes take effect as soon as I edit the file. Is there a way to restart/update the pod without losing changes I might make to this file?

Comment: Store the file on a persistent volume?

Comment: Put your configuration into a `ConfigMap` and then mount that into the pod at the appropriate location. Then you can simply update the ConfigMap (and restart the pod). See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

To store non-confidential data as a configuration file in a volume, you could use [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).

Here is an example of a Pod that mounts a ConfigMap in a volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    configMap:
      name: myconfigmap
```